# Get documents only if all elements inside an array match the condition in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to delete all orphan projects. In db I need to get the projects where all of its users are deleted. Already tried with below query but it's always giving the results where the delete field is absent.

```
db.projects.find({
  "user_list": {
     $not: {
       $elemMatch: {
         "deleted": false
       }
   }
 },
 "user_list.deleted": {$exists: true}
}, {"user_list": 1})
```

Need help in writing a query to fetch the only projects with all user deleted. E.g in below example I should only get the second document.

**List of projects**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("636a6aa584d5f92f14f0c548"),
    "user_list" : [ 
        {
            "deleted" : false,
            "user_id" : "602cf72a3fcad3cc605b8d59"
        },
        {
            "deleted" : true,
            "user_id" : "602cf72a3fcad3cc605b8d50"
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("602e443bacdd4184511d6e29"),
    "user_list" : [ 
        {
            "deleted" : true,
            "user_id" : "602cf72a3fcad3cc605b8d59"
        }, 
        {
            "deleted" : true,
            "user_id" : "602cf72a3fcad3cc605b8d59"
        }, 
        {
            "deleted" : true,
            "user_id" : "602cf72a3fcad3cc605b8d59"
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60332242acdd4184511ed664"),
    "user_list" : [ 
        {
            "deleted" : true,
            "user_id" : "602cf72a3fcad3cc605b8d59",
        }, 
        {
            "deleted" : true,
            "user_id" : "602cf72a3fcad3cc605b8d59"
        }, 
        {
            "user_id" : "602cf72a3fcad3cc605b8d59"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You can also check for the field existence.

Comment: Thanks @prasad_ Yeah tried that also but no result. Let me update the query that I've tried.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`$nin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/index.html) to filter out `false` and `null` values.

```
db.projects.find({
  "user_list.deleted": {
    $nin: [
      false,
      null
    ]
  }
})
```

[MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/K0wxKB-ONkK)

Answer (score 0):

```
db.projects.find(
   { "user_list.deleted": { $ne: false } }
)
```

should give you all the projects which has no record of deleted === false.

you can `$and` it with `$ne: null` for null set to `deleted` to avoid them too.

Updates:
From https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/index.html
I could imagine following to work, but is not valid when I run it on my local machine. This could be because of the nesting.

```
{ user_list.deleted: { $ne: false, $exists: true } }
```

But this one works,

```
 { user_list.deleted: { $ne: false, $ne: null } }
```

Comment: Thanks @Anil but this still results 2nd and 3rd record.

Comment: Isnt the second result you wanted? `I am trying to get the projects when all of its users are deleted`

Comment: Yeah I need the second one but your query fetches second and third result as well

Comment: As I said initially, you could add `$and: $ne: null` like I have showed at the end to get your results.

Comment: @AnilMaharjan `{ user_list.deleted: { $ne: false, $ne: null } }` will only filter out `null` values since `{ $ne: null }` overrides the previous query. It is the same as `{ user_list.deleted: { $ne: null } }`

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan that is not true, adding two condition with comma should actually and them. And testing the query locally, I got different results.

Comment: @AnilMaharjan You can check [this playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sjPX27t-IaO) with the query from your solution returning documents where `user_list.deleted` is either `true` or `false`. Just to make sure, I tested it in a Mongo shell as well.

Comment: I could not access the playground. Update: Now I can.

Comment: I see.. The syntax might be incompatible or something, Because I ran it on my local and it worked, The explanation I added is still true, anding `not equal true` and `null` should return the values and tried following which gives you the required result, I ll check what was the reason behind the query I posted worked for me.
https://mongoplayground.net/p/DVrUu3iu5J3

Comment: Again, looking at your data set I see the problem that I did not see on the original data set on the post so, yeah I see the issues with my query. thanks @Arun

Answer (score 0):

```
db.projects.find({ $and: [ 
              { "user_list" : { $in : ["deleted"] } },   
              { "user_list" : { $elemMatch : { "deleted" : true} } },   
              { "user_list" : { $elemMatch : { "deleted" :{$ne:false}} } } ]});
```

Try with this query. I think it should work in all mentioned cases.